# game shield in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, collision

I am trying to make a shield that will end enemies when they come in contact with the shield. The problem is getting the shield to spawn on the character while he is moving. Any ideas? Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Add empty(which is parented to character bone for example arm) which spawns the shield. and then add logic bricks that parents the shield to the character